# Howto efficiently search a huge mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

if I had a mysql table that has, lets say 300 million rows, how would I search for a row using

```
SELECT id WHERE coloumn = "abc" ;
```

most efficiently? Can I prepare the data so it would help the sql searching through the data? Or does it parse the rows row by row?

Comment: Use Indexes....

Comment: provide your current table schema please (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: also use limit 1 if fetching single row.

Comment: The table doesn't exist yet still in planning stage.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: One important reason of using DBMS is because of indexing feature. Index will group similar data to a table, it used up additional disk space with the benefit of speed.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL 101 answer here is an index using [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE INDEX column_index ON table_name (`column_name`)
```

This of course depends on your schema. You can index more than one column as well and can apply `UNIQUE` constraints to ensure that each value is used only once.

On large tables the `CREATE INDEX` operation will be brutally slow to create the first time, so schedule some downtime if necessary. Once created it will be kept up-to-date automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It will be a huge lookup table. My problem is that I have 5 searchable coloumns and one answer column which column to search will be decided by the php script according to the data entered. Do you think one separate  table per searchable column would be the better solution?

Comment: This depends entirely on your schema. You can have more than one index per table. If you want to find partial matches you might need a full-text index, something that's also an option.